# XMLReader not working when have only 1 data

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, xmlreader

I am using [XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) for converting XML to JSON data.

Code I have is as below.

```
NSString *XMLDataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [data mutableBytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *parseError = nil;
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:XMLDataAsString error:&parseError];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:xmlDictionary
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                          options:0 error:NULL];

    bookShelfArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    bookShelfArray = [[jsonObject valueForKey:@"ArrayOfMagazinesService"] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"bookShelfArray--%@", bookShelfArray);
}
```

Now when I have one object, I get output as below.

```
bookShelfArray--{
    MagazinesService =     {
        AppleID =         {
            text = "";
        };
        CategoryID =         {
            text = 6;
        };
        CategoryName =         {
            text = "\U0645\U062c\U0644\U0629 \U0643\U0646\U0648\U0632";
        };
        ID =         {
            text = 1;
        };
        IsFree =         {
            text = true;
        };
        Name =         {
            text = "\U0627\U0644\U0639\U062f\U062f \U0627\U0644\U0623\U0648\U0644";
        };
        Price =         {
            text = "0.000";
        };
        Video =         {
            text = "http://kanyamakan.hardtask.info/Files/Video/1ce00344-d834-41ea-965c-0ef3c3d1214f.mp4";
        };
        text = "";
    };
    text = "";
    xmlns = "http://tempuri.org/";
    "xmlns:xsd" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    "xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
}
```

When I have two or more object, I have output as below.

```
bookShelfArray--{
    MagazinesService =     (
                {
            AppleID =             {
                text = "";
            };
            CategoryID =             {
                text = 6;
            };
            CategoryName =             {
                text = "\U0645\U062c\U0644\U0629 \U0643\U0646\U0648\U0632";
            };
            ID =             {
                text = 1;
            };
            IsFree =             {
                text = true;
            };
            Name =             {
                text = "\U0627\U0644\U0639\U062f\U062f \U0627\U0644\U0623\U0648\U0644";
            };
            Price =             {
                text = "0.000";
            };
            Video =             {
                text = "http://kanyamakan.hardtask.info/Files/Video/1ce00344-d834-41ea-965c-0ef3c3d1214f.mp4";
            };
            text = "";
        },
                {
            AppleID =             {
                text = "com.apple.test";
            };
            CategoryID =             {
                text = 6;
            };
            CategoryName =             {
                text = "\U0645\U062c\U0644\U0629 \U0643\U0646\U0648\U0632";
            };
            ID =             {
                text = 10;
            };
            IsFree =             {
                text = false;
            };
            Name =             {
                text = dasdasdasd;
            };
            Price =             {
                text = "12.000";
            };
            Video =             {
                text = "http://kanyamakan.hardtask.info/Files/Video/b3c5c107-3f59-49d1-8f25-5111d1b581ce.mp4";
            };
            text = "";
        }
    );
    text = "";
    xmlns = "http://tempuri.org/";
    "xmlns:xsd" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    "xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
}
```

If you see the difference, difference is at

`MagazinesService =     {` & `MagazinesService =     (`

When one object, I have `MagazinesService =     {`

When two or more object, `MagazinesService =     (`

All works fine when two or more object.

When its one object the app crashes. Crash report is as below.

```
2014-03-22 14:44:25.228 xxxxx[16981:90b] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaf92070
2014-03-22 14:44:25.230 xxxxx[16981:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaf92070'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I know nothing about the library you mentioned.  However, it looks like it is generating a dictionary when it has one object, and an array of dictionaries when it sees more than one object.  That is not unusual.

Look at the documentation for that library and see if it has an option to produce 1-item arrays.

Or, you can handle it yourself in your code to parse the JSON data.

From the crash report, you are obviously assuming that the `MagazineService` object is an array (or at least responds to `objectAtIndex:`).

On solution is to accept either when you expect the JSON object to be a `MagazinesService` but always return an array.

```
- (NSArray*)magazinesServiceFromJSONObject:(id)jsonObject
{
    id object = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"MagazinesService"];
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) return object;
    return @[object];
}
```